# Reliably and quickly detect, from Python, whether Spark is installed

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip, dependencies

My team is maintaining a library built on top of PySpark; it requires a working Spark installation to function (which means the user must have Java installed, `JAVA_HOME` correctly set, etc.).

We'd like to be able to automatically detect, whenever our library is either installed (via pip) or imported, whether this dependency was correctly installed, so we print a helpful error message if it wasn't.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: check out [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark)